# Resolving a logical statement

Tags: logic

I would like to test whether `f[n] > 0` and `f[n + 1] > 0` implies `f[n + 2] > 0`.
This is what I tried:

```
f[n] == n*f[n - 2] + f[n - 1];
Resolve[ForAll[n, Implies[n > 0 && f[n - 2] > 0 && f[n - 1] > 0, f[n] > 0]], Reals]
```

I was expecting output `True`, but *Mathematica* doesn't do anything with this.
Any idea what I need to do to have this work the way I would expect?

Comment: @m_goldberg  Basically because the number of variables I'm going to use is not constant, but I see I can substitute y[i] and it's no problem. But now I have a different problem with this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should formulate your problem in its simplest form.

```
Resolve[ForAll[{n, a, b}, n > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0, n a + b > 0]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

You can do it with the complications you introduce into your question.

```
Resolve[ForAll[{n, a, b}, n > 0 && a > 0 && b > 0, n a + b > 0] /. 
  {a -> f[n - 2], b -> f[n - 1]}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

But why bother? They are irrelevant.

Comment: but I do want to use the recursively defined function

Comment: @user31953. Why? If the statement is true for arbitrary `a` and `b`, it is obviously true in your more restricted case.

Comment: Basically I was just making a mistake because I didn't want to have a fixed number of variable, but I see I can substitute some indexed variables where you have a and b. Now I have a different problem with this same statement http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76528/unknown-number-of-variables-in-a-logical-statement